# Expression of italics and superscripts in ggplot axis title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am sorry to ask this, but I can't seem to get this expression right to include in the `ylab()` or `xlab()` arguments of a ggplot2-object. It needs to read:

"*2q* (rarefied)". The "2" needs to superscripted, though.

I have fiddled with `expression()` and `paste()`, but it seems impossible. Any help is much appreciated.

edit: Some example:

```
dat<-as.data.frame(matrix(runif(100), 10,10))
names(dat) <- LETTERS[1:10]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(A,B)) +
  geom_point()+
  xlab("some title")
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: sorry - i thought it was kinda not necessary here.

Comment: you are right, but it saves others from having to generate data to tinker with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All necessary information can be found in `help("plotmath")`.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(A,B)) +
  geom_point()+
  xlab(expression({}^2*italic(q)~textstyle(group("(", rarefied, ")"))))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Isn't that subscript, not superscript?

Comment: just being curious: What if i the leading "2" should be italics as well? xlab(expression((italic({}^2)*italic(D)) does nothing.

Comment: There are limits. I don't think you can combine `italic` and `scriptstyle`. And you probably shouldn't for readability.